# How to use replace function to replace a string exactly and not part of it?

Tags: python

I am an absolute beginner in Python.I am creating a mad lib game which uses replace function to replace words in my template. The following code does not give correct output as template is not changed according to user input.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print("lets play a game of mad libs")
print("you will be asked for a word such as noun,adjective,etc.enter the specified word")

template="""I can't believe its already word1! I can't wait to 
put on my word 2 and visit every word3 in my neighbourhood.
This year,I am going to dress up as word4 with word5 word6.
Before I word7,I make sure to grab my word8 word9 to hold all 
of my word10.
Happy word11!"""

word1=input("enter a  holiday")
word2=input("enter a noun")
word3=input("enter a place")
word4=input("enter a person")
word5=input("enter a adjective")
word6=input("enter  body part (plural)")
word7=input("enter a verb")
word8=input("enter a adjective")
word9=input("enter a noun")
word10=input("enter  food")
word11=input("enter a holiday")
template=template.replace("word1",word1)
template=template.replace("word2",word2)
template=template.replace("word3",word3)
template=template.replace("word4",word4)
template=template.replace("word5",word5)
template=template.replace("word6",word6)
template=template.replace("word7",word7)
template=template.replace("word8",word8) 
template=template.replace("word9",word9)
template=template.replace("word10",word10)
template=template.replace("word11",word11)
print(template)
```

I know I can use flow control loop but I am just understanding string manipulation. So please forgive my messy coding.

The problem with output is that replace function replaces "word1","word10" and "word11" with same input of "word1" because "word1" is part of both.Is there anyway to avoid that instead of just changing name for "word10" and "word11".If not,what alternative to replace function should one use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `string.replace()` will replace all matching occurrences. This is why `word1` is a match for `word1`, `word10`, and `word11`.

If you really want to learn the replace function, it takes an optional argument *count*:

`string.replace(oldvalue, newvalue, count)`

Therefore if the words are sequential, you could try in those lines:

`template=template.replace("word_x",word_x, 1)`

This way each time `replace()` is called, it only replaces the first occurrence.

Another way to do this, assuming you take inputs sequentially, is to use string placeholders `%s`.

For example if we want to take 11 user input strings and then join them to one long string:

```
s = (" ".join(["%s" for i in range(11)]) % tuple([input("Input %d: " % (i+1)) for i in range(11)]))
```

Specifically in your case, it would be:

```
template="""I can't believe its already %s! I can't wait to
put on my %s and visit every %s in my neighbourhood.
This year,I am going to dress up as %s with %s %s.
Before I %s,I make sure to grab my %s %s to hold all
of my %s.
Happy %s!"""  # there're 11 placeholders '%s'

word1=input("enter a  holiday")
word2=input("enter a noun")
word3=input("enter a place")
word4=input("enter a person")
word5=input("enter a adjective")
word6=input("enter  body part (plural)")
word7=input("enter a verb")
word8=input("enter a adjective")
word9=input("enter a noun")
word10=input("enter  food")
word11=input("enter a holiday")

user_inputs = (word1, word2, word3, word4, word5, word6, 
               word7, word8, word9, word10, word11)  # length of this tuple is 11

print(template % user_inputs)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: your answer about count argument solved my problem exactly.I would accept your answer but I think other answers especially about f string,format function and word boundary are correct answers too and a complete answer should be accepted.Can you include their answers also?

Comment: @ak47hil Hello, your question was basically about the replace function so I pointed out the count argument. In my edited answer I also included another approach using %s placeholders. I agree formatted string etc. are great approaches too. There're simply too many ways to manipulate strings...

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expression replacement instead of "simple" string replacement.  Regular expressions let you indicate that you want to match at word boundaries.  This would solve your problem quite elegantly.  For example:

```
import re

str = "word1 word2 word3...word11, word12...word123...word1"

str = re.sub(r'\bword1\b', '_replacement1_', str)
str = re.sub(r'\bword12\b', '_replacement12_', str)

print(str)
```

Result:

```
_replacement1_ word2 word3...word11, _replacement12_...word123..._replacement1_
```

Note how neither replacement touches `word123`, and the fact that `word1` is replaced at both the beginning and the end of the input means that the replacements are indeed willing to do multiple replacements.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is not using `replace()` method but format string with `format()` method and use named parameters (notice that in `template` are now curly braces `{}` and inside them name of parameter that is going to be substituted):

```
template="""I can't believe its already {word1}! I can't wait to
put on my {word2} and visit every {word3} in my neighbourhood.
This year,I am going to dress up as {word4} with {word5} {word6}.
Before I {word7},I make sure to grab my {word8} {word9} to hold all
of my {word10}.
Happy {word11}!"""

word1 = 'abc1'
word2 = 'abc2'
word3 = 'abc3'
word4 = 'abc4'
word5 = 'abc5'
word6 = 'abc6'
word7 = 'abc7'
word8 = 'abc8'
word9 = 'abc9'
word10 = 'abc10'
word11 = 'abc11'

template = template.format(
    word1=word1,
    word2=word2,
    word3=word3,
    word4=word4,
    word5=word5,
    word6=word6,
    word7=word7,
    word8=word8,
    word9=word9,
    word10=word10,
    word11=word11
)

print(template)
```

Prints:

```
I can't believe its already abc1! I can't wait to
put on my abc2 and visit every abc3 in my neighbourhood.
This year,I am going to dress up as abc4 with abc5 abc6.
Before I abc7,I make sure to grab my abc8 abc9 to hold all
of my abc10.
Happy abc11!
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on Andrej Kesely's answer, a more elegant approach would be to use [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) (assuming you're running Python >= 3.6).

```py
word1=input("enter a holiday")
word2=input("enter a noun")
word3=input("enter a place")
word4=input("enter a person")
word5=input("enter a adjective")
word6=input("enter body part (plural)")
word7=input("enter a verb")
word8=input("enter a adjective")
word9=input("enter a noun")
word10=input("enter food")
word11=input("enter a holiday")

template=f"""I can't believe its already {word1}! I can't wait to
put on my {word2} and visit every {word3} in my neighbourhood.
This year,I am going to dress up as {word4} with {word5} {word6}.
Before I {word7},I make sure to grab my {word8} {word9} to hold all
of my {word10}.
Happy {word11}!"""

print(template)
```

Note the `f` before the string literal – that means it's a formatted string.

Answer (score 0):

Replace in reverse order, longest to shortest. `word11` can only replace `word11`. `word10` can only replace `word10`, and by the time `word1` comes around, there won't be any `word10` or `word11` to mix up with.

Alternately, switch to regular expressions, use word boundary `\b` to solve one problem, and get a dozen new ones to worry about.